# sudo fails because of `pam_mount.c` assertion

Tags: 12.04, pam

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 12.04 from 11.10.

Now when I use `sudo` I almost always get:

```
sudo: pam_mount.c:417: modify_pm_count: Assertion `user != ((void *)0)' failed.
```

It makes the command fail.

What is up with that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Login with a root account with `sudo bash`. You can also do this from a live CD. 
Or you need to reboot and do issue a `sudo bash` with the 1st command (it looks like this bug only shows up after the 2nd time you use `sudo`).

```
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive
```

look for line 16(ish) and change

```
[default=1]
```

to

```
[default=0]
```

Try a command with `sudo` and it should work as normal.

[Source from launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-mount/+bug/927828/comments/4)

Answer (score 2):

This misbehavior is caused by a bug in "sudo" package. The above mentioned fix is unfortunately just a workaround that causes pam_denied to run so all authorizations fail and Cron jobs are no longer executed. 
Syslog for instance states:

```
'CRON[process id]: Permission denied'.
```

A patched "sudo" package is available on the following PPA: https://launchpad.net/~intuitivenipple/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=precise

However please note that despite TJ's reputation "sudo" is quite a sensitive package on our Ubuntu system and I advise against installing versions provided by non official Ubuntu or Debian parties.

In any case this bug is referenced by launchpad bug [#927828](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpam-mount/+bug/927828) and triaged as "High importance". Thus a bugfix is likely to be released soon after LTS12.04 has been launched.